# How do I fix "node: command not found" error?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, nvm

I'm trying to run a program (that has been tested on another computer) with `npm start`, but I'm getting the following error:

```
/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 22: node: command not found
/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 37: node: command not found
```

I have installed correct node.js version with nvm and run `nmv use ...`, but I can't really seem to fix this. What am I missing here?

Comment: That sounds like the nodejs binary is not in your system path and thus can't be found when npm tries to run it.

Comment: check if node is installed correctly on your system, run: `node -v`

Comment: @YairNevet doesn't look like it is. Running ```nvm install ...``` says that the version I'm using is already installed